# HTTP Error 500.19 in IIS 10 and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I know that similar questions have been asked but their answer are not solving my problem.

> > HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
> >
> > The requested page cannot
> >     be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
> >     invalid.
> >     Detailed Error Information: Module     IIS Web Core  Notification BeginRequest  Handler    Not yet determined  Error Code     0x80070021
> >     Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this
> >     path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
> >     Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set
> >     explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy
> >     allowOverride="false".
>
> Config File   \?\C:\mySite\web.config
>
> Requested URL      http://localhost:80/mySite/login
>
> Physical Path      C:\mySite\login
>
> Logon Method       Not yet determined
>
> Logon User     Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:
>
> 65:     `</staticContent>`
>
> 66:     `<handlers>`
>
> 67:

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler"
    > preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
    > path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
    > type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
    > Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    > PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I checked in Windows features also and they look alright.

I've tried to set `overrideModelDefault` to `Allow` and to remove `WebServiceHandlerFactory` from applicationhost.congif but no result.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and IIS 10.

Any other ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You need to set overrideModelDefault in machine.config for ReportViewerWebControlHandler

Comment: I do not have a machine.config file

Comment: You will find it in folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config. Framework64 folder in this path may change based on app pool config i.e. 32bit or 64bit

Comment: I've found the file where you said but I don't find what you are saying to modify: https://pastebin.com/pVcqSyLS

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Press Win Key+R to Open Run Window
2. in the Run Window, enter "OptionalFeatures.exe"
3. in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
4. Click: "World Wide Web Services"
5. Click: "Application Development Features"
6. Check the features.

I'm using Windows 10

> Note: "You must be signed in as an administrator
> to be able to turn Windows features on or off." If Windows Features is
> empty or blank, then double-check to make sure that the Windows
> Modules Installer service is enabled and set to Automatic.

**Update:**

Make sure [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) is installed

### Other possible solutions:

#### Solution 1:

Run these two commands from an elevated command prompt

```
%windir%/system32/inetsrv/appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication

%windir%/system32/inetsrv/appcmd unlock config -section:windowsAuthentication
```

#### Solution 2: Using PowerShell

```
Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Features -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-47-ASPNET -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature Application-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature MSMQ -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-WindowsFeature WAS -IncludeAllSubFeature
```

#### Solution 3:  Removing the `<rewrite>` tag in `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite>
    ...
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: most important for NET Core:  Windows Server Hosting bundle https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Answer (score 11):

For me, the problem was a redirection rule in `web.config`.

Solved by removing the entire `<rewrite>`-tag in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
...
...
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: If you need to keep the rewrite rules for your application to work properly, install the module to your local IIS. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 10):

> It's no problem in web.config file.

```
After installation windows, 
IIS does not know how to support .NET Core 2.0 website (or Core 1.0 also) by default
```

You must to install the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting) on the hosting system.

Answer (score 2):

I suddenly started getting this error out of blue when launching debug of ASP.NET project in IIS Express from VisualStudio. While (re)examining the file .vs\config\applicationhost.config I noticed the following suspicious line:

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\My Web Sites\project.Web-Site2" />
```

I would never consciously use OneDrive for anything related to development. But our IT is in the process of adopting OneDrive organization wide. So they probably changed some settings of my profile that caused VisualStudio to update IIS Express config with that path. And "My Web Sites" directory did not exist there. So after I updated the line as following:

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\www" />
```

and created the directory empty C:\inetpub\www, everything started to work again.

Hope this story may save someone few wasted troubleshooting hours.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (VS 2019), I just changed the port in project property / Web / Project URL

and I pressed the button "Create Virtual Directory"

before
http://localhost:40430/XX

after
http://localhost:1438/XX

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install the appropriate Hosting Bundle **after enabling IIS**

In my case:

1. Installed Hosting Bundle
2. Enabled IIS

and got this unhappy message:

`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid`

**Reinstalling** Hosting Bundle solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. For me putting the connection string after configSections which contained the entityframework section, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message, when trying to run regular asp.net applications after installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comparing my C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config with a version from a colleague, we saw that there was missing some sectionsGroup's:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had used the wrong framework. I had chosen .NET 3.5 in my project properties. After changing that to .NET 4 the problem was gone. .NET 4 is the only framework that can be chosen in my IIS 10 version.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a `Web.config` file sharing problem.
Check if the `wwwroot` folder is shared, and also check the
folder which contains publish/build inside.